# Django forms not appearing due to Model as a field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a file management system using Django but not clear how to make Model forms when
there is a foreignkey in the model. Everything I have tried so far did not work.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Files(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField(max_length=144) 
  contet = models.FileField(null=False)

class UserFolder (models.Model):
  folderName = models.TextField(blank=False)
  files = models.ForeignKey(Files, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class UserProfile (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/%y/%m/%d/', max_length=255, null=True, 
      blank=True)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(UserFolder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    file = models.ForeignKey(Files, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Created User model where user can have folders and files. Folder model where folder contains files and at last a model for files.

Forms.py:

```
  class NewFolderForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = UserFolder 
    fields = ['folderName', 'files']

  widgets = {
     'folderName': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'field', 'placeholder': 'folder name...'}),
     'files': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'field input'})
     }
```

I think the main issue lies here as i'm trying to define the files field as an file input field as files is a reference to file model; but i don't know any workarounds to this issue.

Views.py:

```
 def makeFolder(request):
 form = NewFolderForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
 if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     return redirect('home')
 context = {form: 'form'}
 return render(request, 'makefolder.html', context)
```

Just saving the form if it's valid.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
  <div class="title">
 Make Folder </div>
<form class="foldr-creation" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' style="padding-left: 
15%; padding-right:10% ;">
   {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="field">
       {{ form.folderName }}
     </div>
  <div class="field">
       {{ form.files }}
     </div>
 <div class="field">
      <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to be using an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)